# Denormalizing with dataflow in streaming mode

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Let's say I have a stream of question updates and user updates. The streams include the "create" message for each type of entity. Questions relate to users through a questioner_id.

Typical question updates look like {qid: 3 type: "Create", questioner_id: 5}, {qid: 3 type: "Comment"}.

Typical user updates look like {uid: 5 type: "Update" state: "CA"}, {uid: 5 type: "Update" state: "TX"}

And I want a final question_facts dataset that looks something like {ts: x qid: 3 comments: 1 user_state: "TX"} with an entry for every question update and user update that happened after the question "Create" event occurred.

Would the way to do this be to have two PCollections, a window over all time and then CoGroupByKey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input to your pipeline is a fixed dataset, the method you suggest will work.

If you have a stream of updates and you want a stream of output results, you'll need to figure out exactly when you want your output.  For example, you could output every time an update occurs by setting a trigger of AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1) on the windowing of your input.

Comment: Sounds like what we want. The input is streams, and we want a new record every time either of the sources is updated. I'll edit my question. Cheers